# No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon

Tags: pulseaudio

I have pulseaudio starting using this command

```
pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit --log-level=4 --log-target=stderr
```

Is it possible to use pacmd when pulseaudio is started using `--system`? I can't seem to get it to start or even list the sinks.